# Most concise way to split an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

`String` has the built-in method `.split()` but `Array` does not.  Why?

The best I can do is:

```js
Array.prototype.split = function(separator) {
  return this.toString().split(separator)
    .map(egg => egg.split(',')
      .filter(Boolean))
    .filter(egg => egg.length);
}
```

```js
['(', 'name:', 'John', 'Deer', ')', '(', 'name:', 'Jane', 'Doe', ')']
  .split(/\(|\)/);

// [['name:', 'John', 'Deer'], ['name:', 'Jane', 'Doe']]
```

Is there a more concise way to write this, or more efficient to do it, for the **general** case?

Comment: If arrays had a method named `split` I would not expect it to work this way at all. Also, instead of adding methods to built-ins, it is far better to Simply create a utility function

Comment: How would you expect it work?  Splitting a `String` results in an array of strings, so it makes sense to me that splitting an `Array` would result in an array of arrays.

Comment: Since arrays are collections of values of arbitrary type, I would expect it to behave in a manner agnostic to the type of those values and not convert them to strings automatically, Personally, I would expect some kind of chunking or partitioning.

Comment: `[ 'hello, world', '3 / 4', '/', 0.7, '1,2,3' ].split('/')` would return ?  Not what one would expect. I agree with @AluanHaddad the split should match an element, not a string after the array is converted to a string. The result from my example should be `[ [ 'hello, world', '3 / 4' ], [ 0.7, '1,2,3' ] ]`

Comment: @AustinFrance, that's definitely an interesting possibility. It still feels too specific to Warrant adding a member to array though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how does this look:

```
(['(', 'name:', 'John', 'Deer', ')', '(', 'name:', 'Jane', 'Doe', ')'])
    .join(',')
    .replace(/^\(\,|\,\)$/g, '')
    .split(',),(,')
    .map(str => str.split(','))
```

or

```
(['(', 'name:', 'John', 'Deer', ')', '(', 'name:', 'Jane', 'Doe', ')'])
  .join(',')
  .match(/\,?\(\,?(.*?)\,\)\,?/g)
  .map( str => str.replace(/\,?[\(\)]\,?/g, '').split(',') );
```

UPDATE 1 (shortend)

```
function GroupAt( separator, array ){
    return (array)
        .join(',')
        .replace( separator, ',')
        .replace( /^\,{1,}|\,{1,}$/g, '')
        .split( /\,{2,}/ )
        .map(str => str.split(','))     

};

const sample = ['(', 'name:', 'John', 'Deer', ')', '(', 'name:', 'Jane', 'Doe', ')'];

console.log(GroupAt(/[\(\)]/g, sample))
console.log(GroupAt( /(\(|\)|John)/g, sample ))
```

UPDATE: (**see comments)

```
function GroupAt( separator, array ){
        const regString = (separator).toString().replace(/^\/|\/g?i?$/g, '').replace(/\\/, "\\");
    
        return (array)
            .join(',')
            .replace( new RegExp( "^"+regString+"\\,|\\,"+regString+"$", 'g' ), '')
            .replace( new RegExp( '(,?'+ regString +',?){1,}', 'g' ), regString)
            .split(regString)
            .map(str => str.split(','))     
    
    }
const sample = ['(', 'name:', 'John', 'Deer', ')', '(', 'name:', 'Jane', 'Doe', ')'];

console.log(GroupAt(/[\(\)]/g, sample))
console.log(GroupAt( /(\(|\)|John)/g, sample ))
```

Comment: That's useful for my example case but it's not a function that works for all cases in general.  `String.split` allows one to use multiple-character separators, but how would one split an `Array` work with multiple-element separators?

Comment: since you asked, i've added logical continuation of suggested example to be turned into a function, yet I still can't place the `general` necessity of if, rather than a specific use case. Is there a good example to illustrate idea behind generalization over array with some elements being a separator? Are you impling that separator elements of the array have to match you query start to finish or partial match should be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not trying to build a tokenizer?

Here's a naïve one:

```
const tokens = ['(', 'name:', 'John', 'Deer', ')',
                '(', 'name:', 'Jane', 'Doe', ')'];

const result = tokens.reduce((acc, tk) => {
  if (tk === '(') {
    acc.current = [];
    acc.final.push(acc.current);
  }
  else if (tk === ')')
    acc.current = acc.final;
  else
    acc.current.push(tk);
  
  return acc;
}, {current: null, final: []}).final;

console.log(result);
```

The resulting value is:

```
[ [ 'name:', 'John', 'Deer' ], [ 'name:', 'Jane', 'Doe' ] ]
```

Here's something I googled for you: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-math-expression-tokenizer-using-javascript-3638d4e5fbe9/

Also, a quote from Jamie Zawinski:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to string is problematic. Elements should be tested as elements not when combined with other elements. Consider the array:

```js
[ 'hello, world', '3 / 4', '/', 0.7, '1,2,3' ]
```

Here is a solution that does not use string conversion, except when comparing an individual element. Also supports regular expressions.

```js
Array.prototype.split = function(sep) {
  return this.reduce((acc, v, i) => {
    if (v == sep || (sep.exec && sep.exec(v))) acc.push([]);
    else {
      if (i == 0) acc.push([]);
      acc[acc.length-1].push(v);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

Tests:

```js
console.log([ 'hello, world', '3 / 4', '/', 0.7, '1,2,3' ].split('/'));
console.log([ 'hello, world', '3 / 4', '/', 0.7, '1,2,3' ].split(0.7));
console.log([ 'hello, world', '3 / 4', '/', 0.7, '1,2,3' ].split(/^hello/));
console.log([ 'hello, world', '3 / 4', '/', 0.7, '1,2,3' ].split(/^hello$/));
console.log([ ].split(1));
```

Result:

```js
[ [ 'hello, world', '3 / 4' ], [ 0.7, '1,2,3' ] ]
[ [ 'hello, world', '3 / 4', '/' ], [ '1,2,3' ] ]
[ [ '3 / 4', '/', 0.7, '1,2,3' ] ]
[ [ 'hello, world', '3 / 4', '/', 0.7, '1,2,3' ] ]
[]
```